# 12.04 server a little bit broken ( dpkg:error processing gconf2 / can't exec md5sum)

Tags: apt

System is an Ubuntu server 12.04 - and it's a bit broken:

```
root@IT-JOBPROLIN0:~# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.99ubuntu13.5) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up gconf2 (3.2.5-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing gconf2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up libpam-cap (1:2.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Can't exec "md5sum": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl/5.14/IPC/Open3.pm line 186, <STDIN> line 11.
open2: exec of md5sum failed at /usr/sbin/pam-auth-update line 396
dpkg: error processing libpam-cap (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up libpam-ck-connector (0.4.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Can't exec "md5sum": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl/5.14/IPC/Open3.pm line 186, <STDIN> line 11.
open2: exec of md5sum failed at /usr/sbin/pam-auth-update line 396
dpkg: error processing libpam-ck-connector (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up libpam-gnome-keyring (3.2.2-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Can't exec "md5sum": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl/5.14/IPC/Open3.pm line 186, <STDIN> line 11.
open2: exec of md5sum failed at /usr/sbin/pam-auth-update line 396
dpkg: error processing libpam-gnome-keyring (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-55-generic
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 183: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: find: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 183: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: find: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 183: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: find: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 183: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: find: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 183: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: find: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 183: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: find: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 243: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: find: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 253: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: find: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 306: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: find: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 329: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: find: not found
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 6: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: find: not found
E: mkinitramfs failure find 127 cpio 0 gzip 0
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-55-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 gconf2
 libpam-cap
 libpam-ck-connector
 libpam-gnome-keyring
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@IT-JOBPROLIN0:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

In some way last massive system upgrade `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` created the problem with `initramfs`.

I went into `/var/lib/dpkg/info` and renamed the file `initramfs-tools.postinst`. Then I ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` again, and the system rebuilt and reconfigured/recreated this file and now all seems to be ok.